# Spring internationalization: locale change problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a web project with internationalization. It's pretty similar to http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/basic-webapp-internationalization-jsp-example.html.
There are links for switching locales in the decorator. They add lang param to the current url:

```
<a href="?lang=en">En</a> | <a href="?lang=ru">Ru</a> </span></td>
```

At first time internationalization worked fine. But then we found a problem with some forms. 
Form:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/branch/${branchId}/topic.html" modelAttribute="topicDto" method="POST" 
onsubmit="this.getAttribute('submitted')"> <!--Block multiple form submissions-->
<table border="2" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%">
            <form:label path="topicName"><spring:message code="label.topic"/></form:label>
            <form:input path="topicName"/>
            <form:errors path="topicName"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="200">
            <form:label path="bodyText"><spring:message code="label.text"/></form:label>
            <form:textarea path="bodyText"/>
            <form:errors path="bodyText"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addtopic"/>"/>
```

controller:

```
/**
 * @see Topic
 */
@Controller
public final class TopicController {
/**
 * Method handles newTopic.html GET request and display page for creation new topic
 *
 * @param branchId {@link org.jtalks.jcommune.model.entity.Branch} id
 * @return {@code ModelAndView} object with "newTopic" view, new {@link TopicDto} and branch id
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createPage(@PathVariable("branchId") Long branchId) {
    return new ModelAndView("newTopic")
            .addObject("topicDto", new TopicDto())
            .addObject("branchId", branchId);
}

/**
 * This method handles POST requests, it will be always activated when the user pressing "Submit topic"
 *
 * @param topicDto the object that provides communication between spring form and controller
 * @param result   {@link BindingResult} object for spring validation
 * @param branchId hold the current branchId
 * @return {@code ModelAndView} object which will be redirect to forum.html
 * @throws org.jtalks.jcommune.service.exceptions.NotFoundException
 *          when branch not found
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid @ModelAttribute TopicDto topicDto,
                           BindingResult result,
                           @PathVariable("branchId") Long branchId) throws NotFoundException {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("newTopic").addObject("branchId", branchId);
    } else {
        Topic createdTopic = topicService.createTopic(topicDto.getTopicName(), topicDto.getBodyText(),
                branchId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/branch/" + branchId + "/topic/"
                + createdTopic.getId() + ".html");
    }
}
```

}

If the user post the form with invalid fields it will see validation messages before the fields. If he switch page language at that moment he will see the error:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
type Status report
message Request method 'GET' not supported
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Request method     'GET' not supported).
Apache Tomcat/7.0.11
```

you can check the problem yourself at our development server
http://deploy.jtalks.org/jcommune/index.html
for example at registration page
http://deploy.jtalks.org/jcommune/registration.html
leave the form blank and submit it. You will see validation messages. than change the language and submit form one more time to see the specified error.

You can find all our sources here http://fisheye.jtalks.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the porblem by changing the mapping from

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
```

and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the lang parameter to whatever URL brought you to the page. So, if you get to the form via /registration.html, then the En and Ru links lead to /registration.html as well. Presumably that controller supports GET, so when you click on a link and generate a GET request, everything works.

Once you've POSTed the form, the En and Ru links lead to /user.html because, well, that's how you've programmed the page. Click on those links, and you generate a GET request to /user.html. Presumably this fails because the controller for /user.html supports POST but not GET.

FYI you can see exactly what's happening both client side and server side. In either case, use any number of tools to watch the HTTP traffic going back and forth.

Chances are you're using Spring in such a way that switching languages happens server side, so you need to GET the actual page again. To fix your registration form in particular, the easiest thing will be to toss the data that the user already entered, and just switch the link to point to /registration.html even after form validation fails. (In other words, the link should NOT be generated based on whatever URL brought you to the page.) Chances are the user won't switch languages in the middle anyway. However, if you must keep the form data around, then a different approach is required.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But what I can do to avoid this error? I can redirect user to the main page on swithcing language. But it isn't user friendly. May be I can tirm that GET param somewhere before controller?

Comment: I also can set the spirng-specific cookie form javascript instead of passing GET-param. It works good, but I think it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tnink you must use POST/REDIRECT/GET patter.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

For example:

```
@Controller
public final class TopicController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createPage(@PathVariable("branchId") Long branchId) {
    return new ModelAndView("newTopic")
            .addObject("topicDto", new TopicDto())
            .addObject("branchId", branchId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid @ModelAttribute TopicDto topicDto,
                           BindingResult result,
                           @PathVariable("branchId") Long branchId) throws NotFoundException {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("newTopic").addObject("branchId", branchId);
    } else {

       /*Here you must create your topic, and add to DB, then redirect..*/

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/TO_THE_VIEW_PAGE");
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/TO_THE_VIEW_PAGE", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView view(/*need parameters*/) {

    /*...There you must get your topic from DB, and go to view page..*/

    return new ModelAndView("/PATH_TO_THE_VIEW_PAGE");
}
```

If you will need to pass data(object) to the (`view`)method which called after redirect, you can use `RedirectAttributes` class.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/branch/{branchId}/topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid @ModelAttribute TopicDto topicDto,
                           BindingResult result,
                           @PathVariable("branchId") Long branchId, 
                           RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws NotFoundException {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("topic", topicDto);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("branchId", branchId);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/TO_THE_VIEW_PAGE");
    }
}
```

Then get those attributes in the `view` method.